# Cleave.js, getting the country code telephone digit for a particular country

Tags: javascript, jquery, cleave

For Anybody familiar with cleave.js out there. am I able to get the country code digit? in this case here for Italy, am I able to access the 39 for Italy? I am working on a form that will auto complete and show the country code (digits) and could not find a way to grab the digits.

```
new Cleave('.my-input', {
    phone: true,
    phoneRegionCode: 'IT'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes looks right, what error did you see while running.

```
let cleaverObj = new Cleave('.my-input', {
    phone: true,
    phoneRegionCode: 'IT'
});
```

or if you just want to get the information you collected, store the object of Cleaver in any variable like above. so that you can use it anywhere.

Comment: Thanks Rohit. I am still not sure how to access the digit for the country code.

Comment: Well I guess you want to extract the country code itself, so in short you can't do that because Cleave.js will only format input field according to country code